# Positioning radio buttons vertically at the same spot

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to position radio buttons at the same spot vertically while there is a label on the left side. Here is my desired outcome:

[image]

I'm having problems with positioning the second radio button to the same spot as the first one.

Comment: Would be great if you could give us some example of your code, that we can look at (a link to your site or e.g on jsfiddle.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

To align the label to the top relative to the group of radio buttons, use `vertical-align:top` on this label and place the radio buttons in some div; don't forget to make it `inline-block`, otherwise the label and the buttons would stay on different lines:

```css
#radio-group{
    display:inline-block
}
#label{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<span id="label">label</span> 
<div id="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="rg">radio1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="rg">radio2
</div>
```

Comment: Accepted. Just had to wait a few minutes